# Power series modulo polynomials

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I apologize for the lengthy introduction. It is mainly for context and to introduce a certain phenomenon.

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$ Consider the groups $\Z[[x]]$ of formal power series and $\Z[x]$ of polynomials with integer coefficients. I am using $\Z$ here for simplicity, but it may be replaced with any abelian group, as we will see.

I am interested in the quotient group $X_{\Z}=\Z[[x]]/\Z[x]$. For some reason it is difficult to find anything about this group in the literature, but some properties can be deduced. Let us call it the group of 'asymptotes' of $\Z$.

The asymptotes of $\Z$, i.e. elements of $X_{\Z}$ are represented countable sequences of integers $a=(a_i)_{i\in\Z}$, which represent the same element if and only if they differ in at most finitely many degrees. In particular, two sequences represent the same element if and only if they eventually agree. This justifies the intuition of $X_{\Z}$ as modeling the asymptotic behaviour of power series.

There is an exact sequence of abelian groups $$0\longrightarrow \Z[x]\longrightarrow \Z[[x]] \longrightarrow X_{\Z} \longrightarrow 0$$
which has the property that given any abelian group $A$, tensoring with $A$ everywhere preserves exactness (i forget what this property of a short exact sequence is called): We have $\Z[[x]]\otimes A \simeq A[[x]]$ and $\Z[x]\otimes A\simeq A[x]$, and the inclusion $A[x]\rightarrow A[[x]]$ remains injective, so the following sequence is exact.
$$0\rightarrow A[x]\rightarrow A[[x]]\rightarrow X_{\Z}\otimes A\rightarrow 0$$
In particular, $X_A\simeq X_{\Z}\otimes A$ and the asymptotes of $A$ are generated by $X_{\Z}$.

In the analogous situation with $n$ variables, the inclusion $\Z[x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow\Z[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ preserves the $\mathbb{N}^n$-grading, so the same result holds for $n$-dimensional asymptotes.

> Let $E$ be an abelian group and $E=F_0\supseteq F_1 \supseteq ...$ be a decending filtration of $E$. Let $\hat{E}$ be the completion of $E$ with respect to this filtration. 
>   Unless I am grossly mistaken, a necessary and sufficient criterion for the canonical homomorphism $E\rightarrow \hat{E}$ to be a monomorphism is that for every nonzero $e\in E$, there exists some stage $F_i$ of the filtration such that $e\not\in F_i$. Assuming this constraint, we obtain a short exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow \hat{E} \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow 0$$
>   Does this sequence have the property that tensoring with any abelian group preserves exactness?

Also, if anyone is aware of any references where this is treated, I would also accept that as an answer.

I would also appreciate other interesting properties $X_{\Z}$ possesses.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[[X]] \otimes A \cong A[[X]]$ is wrong. The exact sequence is not pure exact. And one reason why you won't find much about $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]/\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is that it is a very nasty object.

Comment: I see. There is a problem with infinite sums, of course. Thank you for pointing it out. Does the failure to be pure exact persist if we replace Z with a (alg. closed?) field? Also, in what way is it nasty?

Comment: The question starts by claiming that $\mathbb Z[X]$ is a [pure submodule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_submodule) of $\mathbb Z[[X]]$ and I find it okay: see [this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331396/pure-submodules-and-finitely-presented-versus-finitely-generated-submodules) and [this file](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/algebra.pdf), page 185.

Comment: Thank you for the references! So the question can be summarized as: "Is an abelian group always a pure subgroup of its completion wrt. a separated filtration?" right?

Comment: @EspenNielsen Exactly. In fact, if one can show that $\hat E/E$ is flat, that is, torsion-free then we are done. (For the example you started with this is almost obvious, and don't really need to follow the steps I gave you as a reference.)

Comment: @user26857 I may do that once I have had time to work a bit more on it, in light of the comments I recieved here.